# GUID model binding in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I was hoping someone could help me sort this out.
The solution to this is probably obvious but I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing...

I'm trying to issue a get request from my Javascript code, and the URL contains a Guid.
The ASP.NET controller does not get hit/register the request to the API.

I've tried a couple different things already but this is my Javascript and Controller as is:

```
        function getChat( contact_id ) {
            $.get("/contact/conversations", { contactId: contact_id })
                .done( function(resp) {
                       let chat_data = resp.data || [];
                       loadChat( chat_data );
                });
        }
```

and...

```
    [Route("contact/conversations")]
    public JsonResult ConversationWithContact(Guid? contactId)
    {

      ... //this doesn't get hit

    }
```

I keep getting this error:

[image]

I'm not sure how to properly bind the Guid such that it is received by the ASP.NET Controller.

Any ideas?? Much appreciated and have a great day!

Comment: send it as string

Comment: It may be unrelated to GUID. The query parameter is optional, so you should be able to access the endpoint even without it. The `contactId` would be null, but it should still be hit.

Comment: Did you add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` to your `RegisterRoutes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route to this:

```
[Route("~/contact/conversations/{id}")]
public JsonResult ConversationWithContact(string id)
    {

      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)){

   var contactId= new Guid (id);
      ... //this doesn't get hit
} 

    }
```

and your ajax:

```
function getChat( contact_id ) {
            $.get("/contact/conversations/"+contact_id)
                .done( function(resp) {
                       let chat_data = resp.data || [];
                       loadChat( chat_data );
                });
        }
```

but if you use very old MVC and attribute routing doesnt work for you, try this:

```
function getChat( contact_id ) {
            $.get("/contact/ConversationWithContact/"+contact_id)
                .done( function(resp) {
                       let chat_data = resp.data || [];
                       loadChat( chat_data );
                });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just tried that. Still not working = (

Comment: @ajavad What is not working? What is your url now?

Comment: @ajavad  - I fixed the action route. Check my answer.

Comment: Tried it. Still no. ugh.                                                                                                   
This is the request URL now:  https://localhost:44321/contact/conversations/091f39d2-6be7-4233-9967-7d6dfda191e0

Comment: What is no? Everything should be working. What are you hiding?

Comment: I know... it ought to be working. Hence my frustration and confusion that it doesn't. I'm not hiding anything my friend lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228863/discussion-between-ajavad-and-sergey).

Comment: That code worked!!: "but if you use very old MVC and attribute routing doesn't work for you, try this:"